# Relative URL with CSS Upgrade

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am developing an application with Ruby on Rails, and I'm using bootstrap to upgrade my CSS.

My question is:

If I have the next URL link:  `link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"`

How can I redefine the URL to be a relative one, thus it will not break if I rearrange my

project's files?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best practice is to put the stylesheets in the following directory:

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```

And include it using:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'name'
```

But if you are using Bootstrap I highly recommend to use a Gem (For example http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails), that way it will handle automatically the stylesheets and javascripts of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use rails assets pipeline. See this guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html